# IPython : Running a .py file using the existing variables

Tags: python, ipython

Is it possible to run a .py code file using the existing variables from previous executions ? I mean to run the new .py file using the variables on memory,that is,the variables I see when I enter the `who` command.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. Provide some example of what you see, etc

Comment: For example, what I'm trying to do is to set a list entering 'myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]' in the IDLE and run a .py file with the code 'print myList' and the command 'run mycodefile.py' so I could print an existing list in the memory with the same name.

Comment: can't you do `import mycodefile` in your code's directory. That should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ipython, use `run -i myscript.py`. from the docs,

> -i run the file in IPython's namespace instead of an empty one. This is
>   useful if you are experimenting with code written in a text editor
>   which depends on variables defined interactively.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the .py file does not define those variables, e.g. you have a "foo" variable in dir() and the .py file specifies a change to foo, then you can use the ipython magic word `%load`.  To see the available documentation for all magic words type the following at the python prompt:

```
In [1]: %magic
```